# What materials form the structural elements of the Boeing 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, aircraft-structures

What materials form the structural elements (leaving the spars, ribs etc) of the B737?

It was tough to get any information on the kind of composites used on the 737 structure. Hoping to get some information on that.

Comment: This question is too vague. I’m not sure what parts you want to know about. I remember reading about Boeing using graphite-epoxy composites for the stabilizers, I think. Maybe be more specific about individual parts.

Comment: I'm working on a college project, which requires me to find material alternatives for the 737. So, I wanted to know what the original components were so that I can search of materials according to their characteristics or even better.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the Boeing 737's structure is made in aluminium. [Composites](http://737b.blogspot.com/2013/07/boeing-737-production.html) are used for smaller parts like the ailerons, the wing-to-body fairings and the tail cone.

It looks like [all of the control surfaces](http://www.airframer.com/aircraft_detail.html?model=B737) are composites.

> Medium capacity airliner series. Aluminium alloy wing structure, upper skin and tail plane, with graphite composite elevator, rudder and ailerons. Glass or carbon fibre-reinforced plastic nosecone, fairings and fin tip. Single or split-scimitar double winglets.

[more composite components](https://www.aerospace-technology.com/projects/boeing737_ng/):

The nosecone, wing and fuselage fairings, fin tips, the fairings of the flap actuators and other non-stressed components are constructed from glass and carbon fibre reinforced plastics (GFRP and CFRP). The rear of the engine nacelles are constructed of graphite, Kevlar and glass fibre composites.

In February 2000 an advanced carbon graphite winglet developed by Boeing became available as an option on the 737-800.